# Why do old willows have so many broken limbs?

Tags: trees, senescence

Willows have a reputation for being very flexible. In a nearby park (PA), where I often walk, there are about 20 willows growing by a stream. Willows over 30' to 40' tall have almost all their major limbs broken off near the trunk, why is this?
Do willows become brittle as they age?
[image: Two severely damaged willows]
I took a recent survey:
All willows over about 30" diameter trunk were severely damaged.
Willows up to about 24" diameter trunk showed no damage, even though some are now taller than those older trees.
Those in between showed little damage.
Some of those damaged willows show heavy infestation of wood boring insects on their trunks and damaged limbs.

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. We would need a little more information on these trees - what species of willow are they? I can see 8 species listed for Pennsylvania. Are the breaks recent (i.e. associated with a weather event - storms and droughts can both cause this sort of damage)? Are the breaks all of a similar age or different ages? A picture might help.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for your comment. I added a picture to my question and some other observations. I do not know which species they are, though younger and older trees seem to me to be the same species. The recent heavy wet snow caused one of the infested trees to fall, and large limbs regularly break off during strong winds and storms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These trees appear to be *[Salix x fragilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_%C3%97_fragilis)* AKA crack willow or brittle willow. The form is more upright and taller than the common weeping willow, but has drooping pendulous thin branches on the lower limbs. We would need to see the leaves for confirmation of species.

These are quite variable in form and are an introduced species in the USA, having origins in Europe and Asia as a cross between two different species, *S. alba* and *S. euxina*.

As the name suggests, the tree is fragile and breaks easily from storm, ice, snow etc.  From the common height of break off and similar diameters of the trees, I suspect that they are similar in age and were hit several years ago by a single weather event.

Given your description of the changes in trunk diameter and younger (smaller trunk) trees not showing damage, I would hazard an event probably well over 20 years ago - perhaps the [Blizzards of '93 or '96](https://keystonenewsroom.com/story/the-5-biggest-blizzards-to-hit-pennsylvania-in-recent-history/).

Comment: so in conclusion, you would say that willow trees do not become more fragile as they age. The group of willow I observed were Salix-x-fragilis "crack willows" which are a very fragile species of willow and most likely were all damaged in a severe storm perhaps 30 years ago.

Comment: @Rich Yes, that's about it. I don't think they become more fragile with age, but I guess a young branch might be a bit more flexible so less likely to fracture?